# Can Agora Record my live and then save it or give me link for it idk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora

I am using Agora for React JS, and I have this kind of question.
Can agora record my live stream and save it, even after that I should save it in my server. can we do smth like that with Agora ?

Code

```
<div className='ui-kit-wrapper'>
    <AgoraUIKit
         rtcProps={ {
            appId: '09883b715deb4c92aa37724e6f6d8548',
            channel: token,
            role: 'host',
            enableScreensharing: true,
            layout: layout.grid,
         } }
         rtmProps={ { username: 'user', displayUsername: true } }
         callbacks={ {
            EndCall: callEnd,
         } }
    />
```

I am expecting it to record my liveStream and then return it to me, with link for e.g.